# she greeted me 'warm'

Tags: adjuncts

> She greeted me **warm**.

In ‘*He died **young***,’ *young* is added as predicative adjunct. Likewise, can the sentence, ‘*she greeted me **warm***,’ be used: ‘*warm*’ is the predicative adjunct for ‘*she*’?

Comment: I think you should mention who used the term predicative adjunct as it is no term of traditional grammar and the term adjunct has several uses. Sounds like one of those superfluous linguistic terms of CGEL. Normally "young" in "He died young" is called subject complement, i.e. a complement referring to the subject. There are object complements, too.

Comment: I think you should mention who used the term predicative adjunct as it is no term of traditional grammar and the term adjunct has several uses. Sounds like one of those superfluous linguistic terms of CGEL. Normally "young" in "He died young" is called subject complement, i.e. a complement referring to the subject. There are object complements, too. The term predicative adjunct means the same as subject complement, but why introduce a new term for something that already has a name. Sometimes I think some grammarians only want to multiply grammar terms, as if the chaos of terms weren't enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, no. When we use *warm* in connection with greetings it neither the greeter or the person greeted we are speaking of but the greetings, so it must be:

> She greeted me warm**ly**.

When we speak of a person as *warm* we generally mean that the person is *warm* on most occasions, not a single occasion.

Note, too, that although any verb can (at least theoretically) take such a secondary predicate, with transitive verbs the predicate will be attributed in the first instance to the object. The attribution will shift to the  subject only if the semantic 'fit' there is distinctly superior. So if you decided to say

> She greeted me warm

most hearers would (after a moment of confusion) take this to mean that her greeting caused you to become warm.